# Swift JSON to Dictionary<String: Any>. Then cast "Any" as NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting, nsmutablearray, option-type

I am trying to read from a JSON String and draw a graph with its data:

```
{"y-axis-data":{"min":0.0,"max":1000,"Step":100.0},"x-labels":[1994,2000,2005],"y-values":[20,305,143]}
```

I wrote a function to create a dictionary from the string:

```
func jsonToDictionary(jsonString: String) -> [String: Any]? {

    if let jsonData: Data = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {

        do {
            return try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [String: Any])!
        } catch {
            some bla bla 
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The return dictionary should count 3 elements inside when I pass my JSON string, and it does.

I can then change of some variables (Double) which are 0 until now and give them the values of min max and Step from the "y-axis-data" key of my dictionary, using `{"min":0.0,"max":1000,"Step":100.0}` as a dictionary it self. Works fine.

My trouble comes when trying to initialize other atributes:

```
self.my_view!.x-labels = (jsonToDictionary!["x-labels"])  as? NSMutableArray
```

my_view has already been initialized as `UIViewCustomClass(frame: someFrame)`

`myview.x-labels` is an `NSMutableArray` and it is initialized as nil. After executing that line of code it is still nill, of course `myview.x-labels.count` is nil. if I do it this way:

```
self.my_view!.x-labels = (jsonToDictionary!["x-labels"])  as! NSMutableArray
```

I get a warning :

> Treating a forced downcast to NSMutableArray as optional will never produce nil.

It then crashes on runtime with this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x110ed5448) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x110ed4598).

of course the exact same thing happens with "y-values"

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Try this : `self.my_view!.x-labels = NSMutableArray(array:(jsonToDictionary!["x-labels"])  as! NSArray)`

Comment: @Amit "cannot asign value of type NSArray to type NSMutableArray"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because your `json!["x-labels"]` is implicitly treated as `NSArray`, so you somehow had to do a "double-force-cast"

```
// get the converted json
let j = jsonToDictionary(jsonString: dict)
// double cast
let m = (j!["x-labels"] as! NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, JSONSerialization class converts into Array, and then Swift cannot cast Array to NSMutableArray. You can do this (Swift4):

```
let array = (jsonToDictionary!["x-labels"]) as? [Int]
if array != nil {
   self.my_view!.x-labels = NSMutableArray(array: array!)
}
```

Comment: This threw the same error. You can check the right answer by Cytus Chang